# post or get multiple values with multiple links

Tags: javascript, href, multi-select

I'm new with this so please be patient with me...

I want to be able to pass multiple variables to another page using links, for example:

```
<a href="value1">some text</a>,<a href="value2">some text2</a>,<a href="value3">some text3</a>,<a href="value4">some text4</a>
```

I want to be able to use this as "multi-selector" so that the user would be able to click (select) what ever text they want and somehow with a submit button send those selected values via post or get.

I don't want to use a menu or list as I'm trying to show text and each link holds different parts of the text, kind of parragraphs in a chapter, so the user would click a paragraph (wich is a link, or at least looks like one) and send it's value to other page, however I want multiple parragraphs so that the user would be able to select and if possible unselect paragraphs.

Hope someone would point me to the right direction if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I might go about implementing this:

**HTML**:

```
<a data-id="value1" href="value1">some text</a>,<a data-id="value2" href="value2">some text2</a>,<a data-id="value3" href="value3">some text3</a>,<a data-id="value4" href="value4">some text4</a>
<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit"></input>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var sz = els.length;

var o = {};
for(var n = 0; n < sz; ++n) {
    els[n].onclick = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var s = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-id");
        if(o[s] !== undefined) {
            delete o[s];
        } else {
            o[s] = "";
        }
    };
}
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function(e) {
    var s = "";
    for(key in o) {
        s += key + "&";
    }
    var location = s.substring(0, s.length-1);
    // redirect user using location as parameter list or send ajax request
};
```

(I use a map rather than an array in the above to avoid having to traverse an array on every click)

http://jsfiddle.net/5y7wK/

Answer (score -1):

The best way to pass multiple values is through a form submission or an AJAX request, you could have multiple check boxes so that when the user selects the values it wants and then sends them in a single request.

Heres a sample : [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Dyge5/1/)

```
<form action="/myurl" method="POST">
        <input id="Val1" name="paragraph" type="checkbox" value="value1"/>
        <label for="Val1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
        In egestas tempus dictum. Mauris purus urna, congue non scelerisque non,
        feugiat at arcu. Donec venenatis facilisis fermentum. Morbi ac lorem odio. 
        Cras nulla justo, pharetra et placerat ut, sagittis nec urna. 
        Praesent luctus, sem ac lobortis aliquam, purus sapien tempor dui, nec 
        pretium metus leo eu ligula. Cras ac egestas dolor. 
        </label>
        </br>
        </br>
        <input id="Val2" name="paragraph" type="checkbox" value="value2"/>
        <label for="Val2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
        In egestas tempus dictum. Mauris purus urna, congue non scelerisque non,
        feugiat at arcu. Donec venenatis facilisis fermentum. Morbi ac lorem odio. 
        Cras nulla justo, pharetra et placerat ut, sagittis nec urna. 
        Praesent luctus, sem ac lobortis aliquam, purus sapien tempor dui, nec 
        pretium metus leo eu ligula. Cras ac egestas dolor. </label>
        </br>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
```